# Sort DATE_FORMAT '%Y-%c' in ASC

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have the query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%c') as month, COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%c'))
FROM sale
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month ASC
```

That returns the following result,

```
month   COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%c'))
2017-10 204
2017-11 178
2017-12 88
2017-7  3
2017-8  1
2017-9  153
2018-1  91
2018-2  86
2018-3  67
2018-4  109
2018-5  131
2018-6  47
2018-7  50
2018-8  36
2018-9  39
```

How do I make the output in correct ascending order? Like,

```
month   COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%c'))
2017-7  3
2017-8  1
2017-9  153
2017-10 204
2017-11 178
2017-12 88
2018-1  91
2018-2  86
2018-3  67
2018-4  109
2018-5  131
2018-6  47
2018-7  50
2018-8  36
2018-9  39
```

I've tried using `MONTH(month), YEAR(month) ASC` and many other options listed on the site. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the data based on [YEAR](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp) and [MONTH](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_month.asp) obtained from `sys_date` directly. Since, you have `only_full_group_by` mode enabled, you will need to get `YEAR` and `MONTH` values in the `SELECT` part, so that `ORDER BY` clause can use it for sorting. Use the following query:

```
SELECT YEAR(sys_date) as ysysdate, 
       MONTH(sys_date) as msysdate, 
       DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, "%Y-%c") as ymonth,
       COUNT(*)
FROM sale
GROUP BY ymonth
ORDER BY ysysdate ASC, msysdate ASC
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month, COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%c'))
FROM sale
GROUP BY year_month
' at line 1

Comment: @S.Sandeep Hi, what is your mysql version ? can you give some sample data as well !

Comment: Hi back. MySQL version is 5.7.23.

Comment: unable to give sample data since the table is too big.

Comment: @S.Sandeep I have edited the query. please check the edited answer. Apparently year_month is a reserved keyword in mysql - so i could not take it as an alias unless I use `

Comment: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'global_sys_copy.sale.sys_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: ok. you have a only_full_group_by mode enabled. Editing in a second to handle this as well

Comment: @S.Sandeep please check the edited query. This should work. Although previous one was working fine for me, because generally `only_full_group_by` mode is not enabled.

Comment: After changing the query to , 
SELECT YEAR(sys_date) as ysysdate, 
       MONTH(sys_date) as msysdate, 
       DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, "%Y-%c") as ymonth,
       COUNT(*)
FROM sale
GROUP BY ymonth, msysdate, ysysdate
ORDER BY ysysdate ASC, msysdate ASC 
It worked

Comment: @S.Sandeep Great! I have added explanation also, for your understanding. You may kindly upvote the answer as well as accept it . thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the calculated `month` is ordered alphabetically.  But you could keep that `ORDER BY month` and simply change it to a format with a leading 0 for months < 10.
That way the string values will all have the same length, and the alphabetical sort will be correct.

Because when comparing strings then '10' < '9' but '09' < '10'

To do that, simply change the `%c` to `%m`.  [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Also, the `COUNT` can be simplified.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%m') as month, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM sale
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

If you do wish to use the '%Y-%c' format?
Then you could include the year and the length of month in the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sys_date, '%Y-%c') as month, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM sale
GROUP BY YEAR(sys_date), month
ORDER BY YEAR(sys_date), LENGTH(month), month
```